# EC2 instance not found from Management Console

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'd like to set up a very basic EC2 instance, connect it to a MySQL RDS database, and install Wordpress. I'm currently using [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/tutorial-ec2-rds-option1.html), and I've created both an EC2 instance and an RDS instance. However, when I try to use the GUI to connect the EC2 instance to RDS, I get a message that "The EC2 instance is not found."

What I've checked so far:

- Both the EC2 and RDS instances are using a test security group that
  allows inbound HTTP, HTTPS, SSH, and Aurora/MySQL traffic from anywhere. (I
  know! I'll fix it once I know what's going on.)
- I kept the default outbound rule (allow all).
- The EC2 and RDS instances share the same VPC security group and the same VPC.
- I can SSH into the EC2 instance and visit its public IP address.

[Error: "The EC2 instance is not found."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29yOG.png)

Answer (score 0):

please check below link, looks like this is a bug

https://repost.aws/questions/QUgL2iz_DbS5K9MX0rErq3_Q/issue-connecting-ec2-instance-to-rds-instance-via-management-console